# SIM900 GPRS: Consecutive AT+CIPSEND

Tags: arduino, gprs, sim900

I'm having some trouble being able to consecutively use `AT+CIPSEND` with the SeeedStudio SIM900 GPRS module on Arduino. This is my sequence of AT Commands (using SSCOM3.2):

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","xx.xx.xx.xxx","80"

OK

CONNECT OK
AT+CIPSEND
> PUT /?data="datasequence"
(CTRL+Z)
SEND OK // at this point "datasequence" has reached the server fine
AT+CIPSEND

ERROR

CLOSED (eventual timeout)
```

I've tried `AT+CIPQSEND=1` as well but got `ERROR` again including specifying length in `AT+CIPSEND`. Am I missing any AT Commands or is it simply not intended for consecutive use? I would really like to avoid closing and reopening the TCP connection.

Additionally will I have better luck using the `AT+HTTP` commands?

Comment: how's the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this for my situation using the HTTP AT command set. [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231224/posting-to-php-server-using-sim900-gprs-with-at-commands) was a big help, I was able to do most of the HTTP commands in the set up function of the Arduino code itself. Then in the loop code I simply set the URL with the `AT+HTTPPARA` command (because this needed to be dynamic - datasequence I mentioned in my first post was tacked on to a URL) and then the `AT+HTTPACTION=0` command to execute the `GET`.